# MySQL, EF6 and Database.CreateIfNotExists

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, mysql-connector

I'm with problems with MySQL not creating the database using EF6. This code works fine in MSSQL Server (just changing the provider to "System.Data.SqlClient"):

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(GetConnection(connectionString),true)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());

        //Database.Initialize(true);
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public DbSet<MyData> MyData { get; set; }

    public static DbConnection GetConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");

        var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        return connection;
    }

}
```

The problem is in the line "Database.CreateIfNotExists();". It throws a NullReferenceException... Both "Database.Initialize(true);" and "Database.CreateIfNotExists()" throws the same error.

My connection string is:

```
Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;Uid=myUser;Pwd=myPassword;
```

The exact same code works fine on SQL Server. I even delete the database, and the SQL Server recreates it.

Doing some tests, using MySQL Shell, I manually created "MyDatabase" and the error does not happen, but the tables are not created.

**Do I need some additional code in order to MySQL auto create the database and tables?**

Other testing: I have added this code instead:

```
if (!Database.Exists())
{
   Database.Create();
}
```

"Database.Exists()" works correctly, the problem is in ".Database.Create()". Really I think I'm missing something here.

*** EDIT ***
My App.Config. (I'm not using a connection string from app.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.10.8.0" newVersion="6.10.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please show your web.config or app.config?

Comment: @er-sho Done. But I'm not getting the connection string from there

Comment: just add this attribute on above your DbContext class and try to enable migration again => `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))] `

Comment: @er-sho what do you mean by "enable migration again"? In MySql is it required? In Sql Server it works as is...

Comment: did u code first right? because you added tag `ef-code-first` so code first require migration.

Comment: @er-sho, Yes, it is code-first, but this is the case, MS Sql Server requires not migration code. So, in MySql I will need create migrations?

Comment: yes recently in past 15 days I have a same problem and after adding above attribute to DbContext, its created a new db to mysql with all tables specified in DbSet.

Comment: @er-sho But do you run migrations via command line, or added some code in addition to this attribute?

Comment: @er-sho Forget it, I finally found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Reading the MySql docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html), I did that 2 changes:

(1) Added this second constructor to my DbContext:

```
// Constructor to use on a DbConnection that is already opened
public MyDbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
   : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
{
}
```

(2) With this new constructor, the code that works to generate the database is:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
   using (MyDbContext contextDB = new MyDbContext(connection, false))
   {
      contextDB.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
   }
}
```

I hope it can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you open the connection before to create the database?

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

//Do stuf with database...
```

Comment: I tested now. Received this exception when trying open the connection: "Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'myUser' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'MyDatabase'"

Comment: It seems that you cannot connect with the database, check the connection string for errors be sure that the format is the correct one.